# Cannot upload file on server nodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch, form-data

Trying to upload pdf file on node js server using fetch() on client and express + multer on server, query status 200, but there is emty object in req.body and empty req.file. Pls check my code below on client.

*client.js*

```
fetch(path, conf) {
  let myConf = config;
  return fetch(myConf.apiUrl + path, conf)
    .catch(err => {
      console.warn('api error: ' + err.message)
    })
},
sendForm(data) {
  if (!data) {
    return
  }

  let header, body;

  const fd = new FormData();
  fd.append('file', data.file.files[0])
  header = 'application/pdf';

  body = fd;

  return this
    .fetch('/connect', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json, application/xml, text/plain, text/html, *.*',
        'Content-Type': header
      },
      body: body
    })
    .then(res => {
      if (!res.ok) throw new Error('error ' + res.status)
      return res
    })
}
```

And server side:
*server.js*

```
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer({ dest: './uploads/' });
const app = express();

app.post('/connect', upload.single('resume'), function(req, res, next) {
  res.send({
    body: req.body,
    file: req.file,
    files: req.files
  })
});
```

Result in Postman: http://prnt.sc/e1ib8o

Comment: try changing the 'resume' to 'file'. That must be exactly the same key used in multi-part form data file upload in front end

Comment: Also, your `Content-Type` needs to be multipart/form-data, not application/pdf, although you shouldn't need to explicitly set the `Content-Type` header (the `fetch()` API should do this for you).